# FirestoreSwift DocumentReference codable

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, codable

I have the following model:

```swift
struct Organization: Codable, Identifiable {
  @DocumentID var id: String? <- Identifiable 
  let ref: DocumentReference <- Reference to the document
  let name: String
  

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name = "Name"
  }
}
```

I need to use the documentRef in my model for references between different databases and different sub collections.

How can I map the ref and make it codable as it isn't a field.

Furthermore do I get the error `Unknown attribute 'DocumentID'`

Using Firebase SDK: 10.20.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes a little different

```
struct Organization: Codable, Identifiable {
  @DocumentID var ref: DocumentReference? //This will be auto-populated when you fetch/Decode.
  var id: String? {
      ref?. documentID
  }
  let name: String
  

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case name = "Name"
    case ref

  }
}
```

In theory you cannot get rid of the `?` since `DocumentID` says `Value` should be `Value?` but you can "pre-populate" the field to minimize the chances that it could be `nil`.

```
struct Organization: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var ref: DocumentReference? 
    var id: String? {
        ref?.documentID
    }
    let name: String
    
    init(name: String) throws {
        self.name = name
        ref = try Firestore.firestore().collection("Organizations").addDocument(from: self)
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Name"
        case ref
    }
}
```

One; what I consider a very dangerous; workaround would be to use `!`. This would eliminate the optional but I don't know if Firebase guarantees that it will never be `nil` on their end. This could introduce a serious bug.

```
struct Organization: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var ref: DocumentReference!
    var id: String {
        ref.documentID
    }
    let name: String
    
    init(name: String) throws {
        self.name = name
        ref = try Firestore.firestore().collection("Organizations").addDocument(from: self)
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Name"
        case ref
    }
}
```

Comment: Since Firebase 10.17.0, `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` no longer needs to be installed or imported. All of its contents are now part of `FirebaseFirestore`. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#cloud-firestore_2

Comment: @PaulBeusterien that is improvement! glad to hear.

Comment: Hi @loremipsum thanks for your answer. Is there a way to not make the documentreference nullable. If it is then I just want it to fail initializing.

Comment: @IT-Guy007 see my revision.

Comment: @loremipsum. ```case ref``` needs to be added to if you want it to be decoded. Please add this to your response.